# android app and servlet

Tags: android, servlets

I am doing a simple application in Android. The Android application has an image button.  When I click the button from the Android client, the request goes to servlet. Now I have a problem getting the string values from servlet to Android client and setting these values in a ListView.

How can I send string data from the servlet and receive the data in the Android client, and how can I set this data in a ListView?

#### Android activity....

```
package com.activity;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class StateInfoActivity extends Activity{
    ListView lst;
    TextView txt;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.state);
        lst=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst);
        txt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
        try{

            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://192.168.1.1:8084/TestApp/StateInfo");
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream in = entity.getContent();

            ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
            String str="";
            while(true){
                int ch = in.read();
                if(ch==-1) break;
                str+=(char)ch;
            }
            //txt.set
            //Toast.makeText(this,str,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

#### servlet

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author Ansh
 */
public class StateInfo extends HttpServlet{

    /** 
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code> methods.
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws Exception {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        ArrayList<String> lst=new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
           Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
           Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ansh","tourism","tourism");
           Statement st=con.createStatement();
           String q="select state_nm from state_detail";
           ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(q);
           while(rs.next()){
             out.println(rs.getString(1));
           }

        } finally { 
            out.close();
        }
    } 

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /** 
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StateInfo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } 

    /** 
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StateInfo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    /** 
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use soap thats the best solution
on android you can use  ksoap2